# How to properly re-seal sliding door

Tags: caulk, sliding-glass-door

My sliding back door has some kind of yellowed caulk/sealant around the glass pane that looks terrible and is detaching in several places. I believe the frame is PVC.

I can remove the old, but what should I use to re-seal?

I can't tell if the old sealant is caulk (it's definitely not silicone, possibly acrylic) or if it was factory-applied or done by previous owners who didn't know what they were doing, so they may have used the wrong caulk or maybe it doesn't need caulk at all.

I don't believe I've seen issues in this area of the door like condensation that would indicate a bad seal or a problematic leak.

[image: detail on door with failing seal]

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this on some sliding doors and glass panels in doors after some age.

This is what I learned from a local door and window manufacturer.  They are not a national brand and this is not a statement in support or against them. Simply repeating the info I received. *Don't shoot the messenger.*

I was told by the door manufacturers that it is a type of glue that hold the glass in place until the actual sealer takes hold.  After some time it looses it's stickiness and weeps out between the glass and frame.  It rarely happens on the outside because the sealer is applied to a greater degree on the outside of the glass.

I was told I can trim it off and throw it away and do not need to worry about anything else.    In my personal experience they were correct. There was no difference in performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily scrape it off with razor, then apply clear silicone. The trick is to use masking tape, apply the silicone, then remove the masking tape while the silicone is still wet.